# Look up SSID my Wi-Fi interface is associated to, based on interface's IP address

Tags: macos, bash, ssid

How can I use bash to get the SSID name of the Wi-Fi network my Wi-Fi interface is associated to, when I know the Wi-Fi interface's IP address?

I get a list of IP addresses by using the `ifconfig` command. I want to display the SSID name along with the IP address as the output. I did check commands like `networksetup`, but found no way to do it. I can go the AppleScript way to get it, but would like to know if there is a way to do it in bash.

I did come across a command that helps me get the SSID name, but it doesn't print the IP address:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
```

I'm running OS X Yosemite (10.10.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X doesn't support multiple Wi-Fi interfaces, so whatever SSID you get from `airport -I` is the SSID for your one single supported Wi-Fi interface.

You could probably write a loop walking through `ifconfig enX` to associate IP addresses with enX devices, and then run `networksetup -getairportnetwork enX` for each one, and whichever one returns a proper answer is your Wi-Fi interface.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using netstat and networksetup -getairportnetwork enX commands